# MySQL (wampserver phpmyadmin) support for ON DELETE

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have created two tables buildings and rooms.

I want the rooms to be deleted if i delete a buildings are deleted automatically.

I know that this can be achieved using foreign key constraints and using **ON DELETE CASCADE**

Here is how I am doing it.

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
    building_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    building_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO buildings(building_name,address)
VALUES('ACME Headquaters','3950 North 1st Street CA 95134'),
      ('ACME Sales','5000 North 1st Street CA 95134');

INSERT INTO rooms(room_name,building_no)
VALUES('Amazon',1),
      ('War Room',1),
      ('Office of CEO',1),
      ('Marketing',2),
      ('Showroom',2);
```

when delete is performed the delete is not being cascaded. 
Is it a problem with phpmyadmin or is there anything wrong in my code (which is highly unlikely) ?

Also does phpmyadmin support ON DELETE statements. If not what should i use.

NOTE : I do not want to delete and recreate the whole table

Comment: Which engine are you using? MyISAM instead of InnoDB by any chance?

Comment: I'm new to MySQL. How and where do i check the engine in wampserver ?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE rooms` should reveal the engine, I think.

Comment: Default storage engine is MyISAM. And I changed it to InnoDB.

Comment: Thanks works when storage engine is InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, Default storage engine is set to MyISAM. MyISAM does not support Foreign Key constraints. From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> For storage engines that do not support foreign keys (such as MyISAM),
>   MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications.

While creating table, you can **explicitly** specify [which storage engine to use](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engine-setting.html) for the table. One such common choice is InnoDB (use `ENGINE = INNODB`). You can use the following queries to create the tables instead:

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
    building_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    building_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

If your tables are already created, and you wish to change the Engine (instead of creating new tables again), you can use the [`Alter Table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) command.

```
ALTER TABLE buildings ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE rooms ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: is it possible to modify the engine for a table already created ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the default storage engine from MyISAM to InnoDB in phpmyadmin/variable/storage engine did the trick. However the tables have to be created again.

Thanks [fancyPant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447489/fancypants), [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen)

Comment: Instead of changing default engine, you can specify the engine type to use in your Create Table statement itself.

Comment: Could you please answer that